# Create a loop using associative arrays

Tags: php, variables, loops, associative-array

I want to put this in a loop because it needs to be repeated 6 times, is it true that using variable variables is a bad practice? Do I need associative arrays?

Basically the 'c1' inside the variable needs to progressively change into 'c2', 'c3'...etc

```
<?php if ($pm_c1_djwd !== '') { ?>

<div>
   <span style="width:<?php echo $pm_width_c1;?>%"></span>
   <span><?php echo $pm_description_c1; ?></span>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: It would help to know where these variables are coming from.

Comment: you coud try var_dump($pm_c1_djwd) and post it here

Comment: Why? The variables are echoing the right data, I only need to know how to change the number at the end of each variable into '_c2', '_c3', '_c4' dynamically so I don't have to repeat the same code 6 times

Comment: Why do you have 6*3 variables to begin with?  Just use nested arrays.

Comment: Right. Any time you feel the need to do this, it's an indicator that you should be using normal indexed arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable variables for the thing you are asking...

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while( $i < 6 ){
$i ++;

$variable = "pm_c".$i."_djwd";
$variable2 = "pm_description_c".$i."";

 if (isset($$variable) && $$variable != '') { ?>

<div>
   <span style="width:<?php echo $$variable;?>%"></span>
   <span><?php echo $$variable2; ?></span>
</div>

<?php } 
}
```

Comment: I think this is still the best solution for my case and it works fine. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Why not try regular arrays?

```
<?php
// Warning: Typed raw in the textarea
$pm_width = array(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);

$pm_description = array(
  "Gizmo",
  "Doodad",
  "Widget",
  "Dohicky",
  "Thing-me-a-bob",
  "Marvelous toy my father gave to me."
);

$pm_c1_djwd = "Snod";

if ($pm_c1_djwd !== '') {

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($pm_description); $i++) {
    $width = $pm_width[$i];
    $desc = $pm_description[$i];

    echo "<div>";    
    echo "<span style='width:${width}%'>$desc</span>";     
    echo '</div>';
    echo PHP_EOL;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a variable for each field like `$pm_description_c1`, `..c2` and so on, put them in an associative array:

```
$pms = array(
    array('description' => 'your description', 'width' => '123px', 'djwd' = 'what'),
    array('description' => 'Second item', 'width' => '123px', 'djwd' = '')
);
```

Then loop through them:

```
<?php
foreach ($pms as $pm) {
    if ($pm['djwd' !== '') {
    ?>
        <div>
            <span style="width:<?php echo $pm['width'];?>%"></span>
            <span><?php echo $pm['description']; ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```